AWSappsync query returns Nil after updating it 3+
I just migrated Xcode to 15 this made other pod file to get updated, after updating app sync 3+ I'm getting a nil response
func configureAppSync() {
  //AWS AppSync Initialization do {
  let appsyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(appSyncServiceConfig: AWSAppSyncServiceConfig(), cacheConfiguration: AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration())
  appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appsyncConfig) {
    print("configureAppSync success", appSyncClient)
  } catch {
    print("configureAppSync error", error  
  }
}

func testAppsyncQuery(){
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: self.sendLanguageCode())

  let getMonthSalesDetailsQuery = GetMonthSalesDetailsQuery(sapCode:  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sapCode")!, dateValue: dateFormatter.string(from: self.date))
        
  // Print the GraphQL query payload
  let queryPayload = getMonthSalesDetailsQuery.variables
  print("GraphQL Query Payload: \(queryPayload)")
        
  appSyncClient?.fetch(query: getMonthSalesDetailsQuery, cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheData, queue: DispatchQueue.main, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
      debugPrint("testAppsyncQuery Error fetching data: \(error)")
      return
    }

    if let data = result?.data {
      // Process your data here
      debugPrint("testAppsyncQuery Fetched data: \(data)")
    }
  })
}

getting a response like this
testAppsyncQuery Fetched data: Data(snapshot: [\"getMonthSalesDetails\": nil])

Can anyone please help on this? Why I'm getting this error?
